# What words are there for sexual intercourse and menses that cover the particular meaning but are not very straight?

Tags: word-request

I've read in a book that to be polite in a conversation we may use past tense and this is called distancing. Such as, rather than saying *'I want to go.'* one may say:

*I wanted to go.*

Although the speaker is there where the listener is, and he is saying this thing right then. This sentence doesn't refer to any of his past wish or polite request. He wants to remain very polite while being listened to. Like we say:

I need to go to the restroom.

'**restroom**' instead of '**toilet**'

**Cloakroom** is also a word that covers this.*

For instance, '**sexual intercourse**' or '**menses**' are words that are somehow blunt while you're speaking to audiences both adult and under-age. You may need to say something of this sort due the topic requirement.

QUESTION:What words are there for these two [sexual intercourse and menses], words that cover the particular meaning but are not very straight?

Comment: I'm very confused. Are there two unrelated questions here? How does the past tense have anything to do with the choice of "restroom" vs. "toilet"? And what book did you read this in?

Comment: Past has been mentioned for TENSE CHANGING, not for the vocab. My question is about distancing words used instead of menses and sexual intercourse

Comment: @ TypeIA  now read the question please

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for euphemisms for those two terms.

For sex, there are many. They depend on how formal/informal you want to be. There are dozens, but here are just a couple common ones that are formal or somewhat formal:

> - [intercourse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intercourse)
>     3 : physical sexual contact between individuals that involves the genitalia of at least one person
>     // anal intercourse
>     // oral intercourse
>     especially : [sexual intercourse sense 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sexual%20intercourse)
>     // heterosexual intercourse
> - [relations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relation)
>     7a : the state of being mutually or reciprocally interested (as in social or commercial matters)
>     b **relations** plural
>     (1) : dealings, intercourse
>     // foreign relations
>     (2) : sexual intercourse
>
> (M-W)

Here are a couple less formal ones, especially the second pair:

> - - [lovemaking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lovemaking)
>       1 : sexual activity especially : copulation
>   - [make love](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make)
>       1a : to engage in sexual intercourse
>       (M-W)
> - - [it](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/it)
>
>     14. Slang.
>           a sex appeal.
>           b. sexual intercourse
>           (Dictionary.com)
>   - [do it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do)
>       : to have sexual intercourse
>       (M-W)

I mean, there are literally hundreds for sex, according to this list: [400 Euphemisms For Sexual Intercourse](https://thoughtcatalog.com/jim-goad/2014/12/400-euphemisms-for-sexual-intercourse/). I didn't go through all of them, but most of them seemed informal, and some seemed kind of silly.

Here's a page with a few and some explanatory notes: [26 Amazing Historical Euphemisms For Sex, Because You Could Stand To Have Your Corn Ground](https://www.bustle.com/articles/69554-26-amazing-historical-euphemisms-for-sex-because-you-could-stand-to-have-your-corn-ground).

Admittedly, I know a lot less about *menses*. I don't know of any particular euphemism for the actual tissue, but here are a couple for menstruation:

> - [period](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/period)
>
>   7. countable noun
>        When a woman has a period, she bleeds from her uterus. This usually happens once a month.
>        *Can you get pregnant if you have sex during your period?*
>        (Collins Dictionary)
> - [time of the month](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/time_of_the_month)
>     phrase
>     euphemistic
>     The time during which a woman or girl has her period; an occurrence of menstruation.
>     ‘they assume that if I am upset about anything, it must be my time of the month’
>     (Lexico)

There are others for menstruation. Here are some in an article, but again, they're mostly informal (the English language ones): [Menstruation study finds over 5,000 slang terms for 'period'](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/menstruation-study-finds-over-5000-slang-terms-for-period-a6905021.html).